# Getting results between two dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, overlap

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id        | user_id   | start_date | end_date |
| (integer) | (integer) | (date)     | (date)   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Fields `start_date` and `end_date` are holding date values like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

An entry from this table can look like this: `(1, 120, 2012-04-09, 2012-04-13)`.

I have to write a query that can fetch all the results matching a certain period.

The problem is that if I want to fetch results from `2012-01-01` to `2012-04-12`, I get 0 results even though there is an entry with `start_date = "2012-04-09"` and `end_date = "2012-04-13"`.

Comment: @MarcoMariani I want it to be able to work just like in the example.

Comment: The question doesn't really say what "matching" means.  Containing?  Contained by?  Overlapping?  An exact match?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
 SELECT *
   FROM mytable
  WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2012-01-01'::DATE, '2012-04-12'::DATE);
```

[Datetime functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) is the relevant section in the docs.

Comment: It was not my question directly, however, using OVERLAPS saved my day. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 40):

Assuming you want all "**overlapping**" time periods, i.e. all that have at least one day in common.

Try to envision time periods on a straight time line and move them around before your eyes and you will *see* the necessary conditions.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  start_date <= '2012-04-12'::date
AND    end_date   >= '2012-01-01'::date;
```

This is sometimes faster for me than `OVERLAPS` - which is the other good way to do it (as [@Marco already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171439/939860)).

Note the subtle difference. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

> `OVERLAPS` automatically takes the earlier value of the pair as the
> start. Each time period is considered to represent the half-open
> interval **`start <= time < end`**, unless start and end are equal in which
> case it represents that single time instant. This means for instance
> that two time periods with only an endpoint in common do not overlap.

Bold emphasis mine.

#### Performance

For big tables the right **index** can help performance (*a lot*).

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_date_inverse_idx ON tbl(start_date, end_date DESC);
```

Possibly with another (leading) index column if you have additional selective conditions.

Note the inverse order of the two columns. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)

Answer (score 26):

just had the same question, and answered this way, if this could help.

```
select * 
from table
where start_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-04-13'
or    end_date   between '2012-01-01' and '2012-04-13'
```

Answer (score 4):

To have a query working in any locale settings, consider [formatting the date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) yourself:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM testbed 
 WHERE start_date >= to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND end_date <= to_date('2012-04-13','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dates for which it doesn't work -- those where the day is less than or equal to 12 -- I'm wondering whether it's parsing the dates as being in YYYY-DD-MM format?

Comment: Why not? This format depends on the clients' locale settings, database stores it in a couple of bytes, without any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the date part fetching method:

```
SELECT * FROM testbed WHERE start_date  ::date >= to_date('2012-09-08' ,'YYYY-MM-DD') and date::date <= to_date('2012-10-09' ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense but to check for performance of sql I executed some of the above mentioned solutiona pgsql.

Let me share you Statistics of top 3 solution approaches that I come across.

1) Took : 1.58 MS Avg

2) Took : 2.87 MS Avg

3) Took : 3.95 MS Avg

Now try this :

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_TRUNC('day', date ) >= Start Date AND DATE_TRUNC('day', date ) <= End Date
```

Now this solution took : 1.61 Avg.

And best solution is 1st that suggested by [marco-mariani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74305/marco-mariani)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ecs_table
WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2012-01-01'::DATE, '2012-04-12'::DATE + interval '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `range` data type.

--sample data.

```
begin;
create temp table tbl(id  serial, user_id integer, start_date date, end_date date);
insert into tbl(user_id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2012-04-09', '2012-04-13');
insert into tbl(user_id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2012-01-09', '2012-04-12');
insert into tbl(user_id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2012-02-09', '2012-04-10');
insert into tbl(user_id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2012-04-09', '2012-04-10');
commit;
```

add a new daterange column.

```
begin;
alter table tbl add column tbl_period daterange ;
update tbl set tbl_period = daterange(start_date,end_date);
commit;
```

--now test time.

```
select * from tbl
    where tbl_period && daterange('2012-04-10' ::date, '2012-04-12'::date);
```

returns:

```
 id | user_id | start_date |  end_date  |       tbl_period
----+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------
  1 |       1 | 2012-04-09 | 2012-04-13 | [2012-04-09,2012-04-13)
  2 |       1 | 2012-01-09 | 2012-04-12 | [2012-01-09,2012-04-12)
```

further reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE