# Non-overlap, continuous timestamp ranges (tstzrange) for opening hours

Tags: postgresql, database-design, indexing, range-types

```
CREATE TABLE operating_period (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  during TSTZRANGE NOT NULL,
  -- other meta fields
);
```

Requirements:
1. No operating period can overlap with each other

Question:

1. How do I add a constraint to make sure that there is no overlap in the operating hours?
2. In terms of query speed, am I better off with two columns `(start_at, end_at)` or is GIST index fast for `tstzrange`?
3. In schema design, is `tstzrange` commonly used? Or am I better of with two columns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to **1.** is clear. To make sure there is no overlap use an [**exclusion constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT):

```sql
CREATE TABLE operating_period (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY                -- PK is NOT NULL automatically
, during tstzrange NOT NULL
, EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)  -- no overlap
);
```

This is implemented with a GiST index on `during`, that supports many types of queries automatically. See:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)
- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/native-way-of-performing-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)

Answers to **2.** and **3.** are not as clear because those really depend on a lot of things. For opening hours I would most likely go with range types in current versions of Postgres. I would also enforce `[)` bounds for all entries to keep things simple. Details in the [first linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869).

If you should go with `(start_at, end_at)`, you'll be interested in the [`OVERLAPS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) operator:

- [Getting results between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170544/getting-results-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/10174704)
- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480715/find-overlapping-date-ranges-in-postgresql/15305292)

<sub>Either way, the guideline on SO is to ask *one* question per question, not a whole list ...</sub>