# How to ensure entries with non-overlapping time ranges?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, database-design, exclusion-constraint

I need to ensure my database only contains entries where two or more of its columns are unique. This can easily be achieved with a `UNIQUE` constraint over those columns.

In my case, I need to forbid duplication only for overlapping time ranges. The table has `valid_from` and `valid_to` columns. In some cases one might first need to expire the active entry to by setting `valid_to = now`, and then inserting a new entry adjusted to `valid_from = now` and `valid_to = infinity`.

I seem to be able to expire the prior entry without any problems using `UPDATE`, but inserting the new entry seems to be troublesome since my base columns are currently `UNIQUE`, and therefore can't be added again.

I thought of adding `valid_from` and `valid_to` as part of the `UNIQUE` constraint, but that would just make the constraint more loose, and allow 
duplicates *and* overlapping time ranges to exist.

How do I make a constraint to ensure that duplicates don't exist with overlapping `valid_from` and `valid_to` `tsrange`?

I seem to be looking for `EXCLUDE USING GIST`, but it does not seem to support multiple columns? This does not seem to work for me:

```
ALTER TABLE registration 
DROP Constraint IF EXISTS registration_{string.Join('_', listOfAttributes)}_key, 
ADD Constraint registration_{string.Join('_', listOfAttributes)}_key EXCLUDE USING GIST({string.Join(',', listOfAttributes)} WITH =, valid WITH &&);
```

Comment: The *exact* (minimal) table definition would be instrumental (`CREATE TABLE` statement). And always your version of Postgres. Also, *why* does your solution not seem to work? Any error msg? Are you free to install extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. But the [syntax for exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) is slightly different.

Depending on the undisclosed table definition, you may need to [install the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264961/939860) (additional module) [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) first. Once per db. It's needed for this solution to provide the required operator class for type `integer`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL EXCLUDE USING error: Data type integer has no default operator class](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37351/3684)
- [How to use (install) dblink in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql/13264961#13264961)

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE registration  (
  tbl_id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
, col_a  integer NOT NULL
, col_b  integer NOT NULL
, valid_from timestamp
, valid_to   timestamp
, CONSTRAINT no_overlap
    EXCLUDE USING gist (col_a with =, col_b with =, tsrange(valid_from, valid_to) WITH &&)
);
```

Each column needs to be listed with its respective operator.

And you need a *range type*. You mention separate columns `valid_from` and `valid_to`. And you also mention `tsrange` and `valid` in the failed command. That's confusing. Assuming two `timestamp` columns, an expression index with the expression `tsrange(valid_from, valid_to)` would do it.

Related:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)
- [Non-overlap, continuous timestamp ranges (tstzrange) for opening hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539259/non-overlap-continuous-timestamp-ranges-tstzrange-for-opening-hours/26539981#26539981)
- [Postgresql 9.4 query gets progressively slower when joining TSTZRANGE with &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987739/postgresql-9-4-query-gets-progressively-slower-when-joining-tstzrange-with/33990737#33990737)
- [Store the day of the week and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895140/store-the-day-of-the-week-and-time/19897592#19897592)

Typically, `timestamptz` (`tstzrange`) should be chosen over `timestamp` (`tsrange`). See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- [Don't use timestamp (without time zone)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29)

---

*Maybe*, a superior design would be a one-to-many relationship between your `registration` table and 1-N entries in a new `registration_range` table. And some logic to determine the currently valid entry (for any given point in time). Depends on more undisclosed information.