# Using to_char in where clause

Tags: postgresql, date, to-char

Does anyone know why when I use the following I don't get any results:

```
where 
TO_CHAR(aa.timestamp :: date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '07/01/2021'
AND 
TO_CHAR(aa.timestamp :: date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= '06/30/2022'
```

But when I change the month I can:

```
where 
TO_CHAR(aa.timestamp :: date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '07/01/2021'
AND 
TO_CHAR(aa.timestamp :: date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= '07/30/2022'
```

I'm trying to get a count of activity from a financial year. The aa.timestamp is in timestamp without time zone format on a Postgres Db.

Comment: Because you are comparing two strings so you are getting lexicographical sort order, like a dictionary. Don't convert a date to a string, just compare the `timestamp` to a date literal.

Comment: that is a string comparison, so the rules for dates does not work

Comment: Take a look at the answers here for a better way of doing this: [Getting results between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170544/getting-results-between-two-dates-in-postgresql)

Comment: Because the date field being passed from another source is in the MM/DD/YYYY format I needed to figure out how to compare two dates in that format against the timestamp format. I think I've figured it out though.  `aa.timestamp >= to_timestamp( '07/01/2021','MM/DD/YYYY')
and aa.timestamp <= to_timestamp( '06/30/2022','MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert your timestamp to a string, compare it to a date:

```
where aa.timestamp >= date '2021-01-07'
  AND aa.timestamp < date '2022-07-01'
```

Note that I changed the upper limit one day after the date you specified, but changed the operator from `<=` to `<`