# How do you query future date ranges to look for valid DATERANGE?

Tags: postgresql

I've made a previous post over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401562/how-do-you-query-between-date-ranges-to-look-for-valid-daterange?noredirect=1#comment133046317_75401562) going through date ranges in that is current and in the future.

However, I've not specified enough to include dates that would only happen in the future. I'm making a new post since there are no current post addressing this. Considering date ranges are a "weird" data type I figured it'd be best to address this in a separate post.

Say my table is this

```
validity table
 id          |     validity_dates      
-------------+-------------------------
          1 | [2018-01-01,2019-01-01)
          2 | [2017-05-01,2017-06-01)
          3 | [2016-05-01,2016-07-01)
          4 | [2022-01-01,2025-01-01)
          5 | [2024-01-01,2026-12-10)
```

How do I query to get the id based on whether the date range between validity_dates exists in the future?

For example I want to get id's that are valid in future. I run a query and get a return on `id 5` since the validity dates starts in `2024`.

My current implementation doesn't work in the sense it provides only dates that contain the current date into the date ranges and returns `id 4`

```
SELECT id
FROM validity
WHERE current_date <@ validity_dates
```

How do I best approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lower](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)():

```
SELECT id
FROM validity
WHERE current_date < LOWER(validity_dates);
```